# get object integer json to android studio

Tags: android, json, android-volley

[json with int key value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1m4l.png%60)

I've been stuck, to call json like this to android studio using volley, I've never done this before

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse JSON in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-do-i-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: can you paste your json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [json with int key value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1m4l.png%60)
you are

> receiving jsonArray instead of jsonObject

so you have to

> send the request of JsonArray with volley

then the request will return jsonArray then you can get your string like this.

```
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest("url", new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response)
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i=0;i<response.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray(i);
                    for (int j=0;j<jsonArray.length();j++)
                    {
                        String yourString = jsonArray.getString(j);
                        // you can convert it into int as per your requirement
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {

                }
            });
```